# How to handle special characters like " ’ " when fetched from DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Actually, i have an entry in my db of title **"You’re Accepted to College, Now What: Deciding Upon..."**.

So when user types "you'are accepted...." it doesn't match with the above because of the special character **’**.

What should be done for such type of characters.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: They should match if they are the same. Probably they are not the same. You should show us the `inspect` result of both strings.

Comment: They are different as the db entry contains special **Apostrophe ’ symbol**. But a normal user cannot enter that special apostrophe. we can just type the keyboard **quotes '**. 


See they both are different .Issue is with the character encoding. So what should be done to solve this problem ? Should i chnage the entry in db .. If yes how ? As there can be any number of such records.

Comment: If you have a non-usual symbol, then it is better to normalize that in the database. Don't save them as are in the database. Save after converting them to an ASCII character.

Comment: Now if they are already saved in db.. And it can be of any number as data is imported from other site. 

So how to convert them in ASCII now ?

Comment: that's what fulltext indices like lucene are for.

Answer (score 0):

So in the case that you do have the apostrophe within your database in all places, so that there is no record that has a quote instead, I'd just correct the queries via gsub so that they contain the correct quote.

The true, nice and elegant solution would be to add a collation to your database server. The collation is what makes the database return `1` for `SELECT 'ä' LIKE 'a'`. Unfortunately, neither utf8_general_ci nor utf8_unicode_ci (which are built-in collations to MySQL) fold the apostrophe together with the quote. This is why you would have to add a new one. How this is accomplished in MySQL, you may find here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/adding-collation.html